# Python Threading: Running 2 different functions simultaneously

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a function `foo` that only stops once a condition has been met. While `foo` is running, I need to ask for user input the whole time (keeps asking for user input). I want them to run separately without interfering with each other.

In my example below, `foo` keeps printing 'Hello' and `getUserInput` keeps looking for user input. I want foo to keep printing hello even if i do not enter anything for user input. It will keep asking for input as long as the user does not enter letter 'e'. I have my attempt below:

```
import threading
from time import sleep

class test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True

    def foo(self):
        while(self.running):
            print 'Hello\n'
            sleep(2)

    def getUserInput(self):
        x = ''
        while(x != 'e'):
            x = raw_input('Enter value: ')
        self.running = False

    def go(self):
        th1 = threading.Thread(target=self.foo)
        th2 = threading.Thread(target=self.getUserInput)
        th1.start()
        th2.start()


t = test()
t.go()
```

My code prints out the first hello and asks for input but nothing after that. What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: If you don't enter anything at all, does it still keep printing 'hello'?

Comment: Which version of python are you running?

Comment: 2.6.1 on OSX 10.6.8.  Also works on 2.5.4 and 2.7.2.

Comment: Well thats just strange for me then. I have 32 bit python, 2.7.2, on windows 7 (64 bit, some of my modules were acting incompatible with 64 bit hence 32 bit python). Thanks for your input by the way.

Comment: Works fine here on python 2.7.2 FreeBSD amd64 (64 bit).

Comment: I ran it on another machine and I encountered the same problem. Maybe I am not clarifying my objective/goal properly.

I want both threads to run independent of each other where you have 'hello' print out every 2 seconds regardless of the input/or no input. 

Currently, Its not printing the next 'hello' unless I do enter some input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update:** *The opener was running his code on Windows in IDLE. Regarding I/O it behaves differently than a shell or the Windows command line. His code works on the Windows command line.*

In principle, your code works for me. I am running Python 2.6.5.

Several comments here:

1) In your case it would be fine to only have two threads: the main thread and another one. However, it will also work with three. It's just that your main thread does nothing else than waiting for the other threads to finish.

2) You should to explicitly `join()` all threads you spawn. You do this in the main thread before terminating it. Keep record of the threads you spawn (e.g. in a list `threads`) and then join them at the end of your program (e.g. `for t in threads: t.join()`).

3) You share the variable `self.running` between threads. It is fine in this case, as one thread only reads it and another one only writes it. In general, you need to be very careful with shared variables and acquire a lock before changing it.

4) You should catch the `KeyboardInterrupt` exception in the main thread and find a way to communicate to your other threads to terminate :)

5) Use lowercase method names, so instead of `getUserInput` call it `get_user_input`. Use uppercase class names and inherit from `object`: `class Test(object):`

This is a running example:

```
import threading
from time import sleep


def main():
    t = Test()
    t.go()
    try:
        join_threads(t.threads)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "\nKeyboardInterrupt catched."
        print "Terminate main thread."
        print "If only daemonic threads are left, terminate whole program."


class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.running = True
        self.threads = []

    def foo(self):
        while(self.running):
            print '\nHello\n'
            sleep(2)

    def get_user_input(self):
        while True:
            x = raw_input("Enter 'e' for exit: ")
            if x.lower() == 'e':
               self.running = False
               break

    def go(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.foo)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.get_user_input)
        # Make threads daemonic, i.e. terminate them when main thread
        # terminates. From: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3788243/145400
        t1.daemon = True
        t2.daemon = True
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        self.threads.append(t1)
        self.threads.append(t2)


def join_threads(threads):
    """
    Join threads in interruptable fashion.
    From http://stackoverflow.com/a/9790882/145400
    """
    for t in threads:
        while t.isAlive():
            t.join(5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When typing e or E, the program ends after a short delay (as intended by you). When pressing ctrl+c, it immediately terminates. Making a program that uses `threading` responsive to exceptions is a bit trickier than expected. I have included important references in the source above.

This is how it looks like during runtime:

```
$ python supertest.py

Hello

Enter 'e' for exit: 
Hello


Hello


Hello

e
$
```

Comment: Thank a lot. I really appreciate your efforts. I am on Python 3.2.3 now and I am still getting the same behavior even with your code. 'hello' is printed once and then the console just waits for my input without any continuous printing of 'hello' . Any thoughts?

Comment: I will edit the answer again and show you how the output looks like for me. Edit: done.

Comment: Yes I tried it on 2.7 as well as Python 3 on 2 different hardwares.

Comment: How do you invoke that script? From Windows commandline or do you work with IDLE?

Comment: i am working with IDLE. and it only prints the next 'hello' once I enter some input even on a 32 bit windows XP

Comment: IDLE is a very special environment. It is for development, not for production. Please run the code from windows commandline: `c:\path\to\python.exe test.py`

Comment: IDLE might be blocking the output while it's waiting for input. so your thread might be trying to print 'hello' but idle isn't letting it until the input gets resolved. yes, run it in the commandline

Comment: Well this is embarrassing, yes it does work now. Thank you so much. I'll make sure to run everything from command line from now on. I am still learning python :)

Comment: @AasamTasaddaq, this is very fine. It's an implementation detail of IDLE and you are not to blame for not knowing this. I think you've learned a lot while cracking on this problem anyway :)

Comment: That is very true and I am glad I had this problem.

Comment: And don't forget thinking about accepting an answer ;) Good night!